# Network Breach - Possibility

Tags: network, breach

Hypothetically, if someone had unauthorized access to my network, there are a lot of things that can happen, depending on the point of attack and how it accessed, I can assume that anything that is connected to the network can have potential to be monitored or hacked.

I don't know enough jargon to ask a specific question and understand that there are many ways to attack a network, so I would just like to know if the following is possible, not how it's done:

1) can someone know/view what websites someone is going to, what emails they're writing and the content, can access camera and record audio/video?

2) I've seen products, equipment, etc online that anyone can buy for the purpose of being able to monitor/record phone conversations, either through an app or some device (have seen them in the $1000's). There has to be something out there that consumers can buy for this purpose, maybe even police grade or government stuff. Possible?

3) Would it be fair to say that if someone had access to my network, that no matter what I do with the hardware, as long as they have that network access, that it would still be able to be hacked or monitored?

The broad question is on purpose, as I'm not looking for a particular solution, nor am I asking for the likelihood of this happening.

Also, if we could put aside the skill level/costs/motive it would take for someone to do this as well.

Comment: The answers to these questions depend on so many unknowns that cannot be answered in a useful way unless you give more information. What kind of setup are we talking about? Is it commercial? How likely is that someone would want to hack your network? Who is in charge of the security?

Comment: Shorty answers: 1) depends on the machine compromised, if everything is compromised, then all that you are asking can be done easily. 2) depends a lot on your country's laws and whether you are willing to break them (I would advise against it) and whether you are the administrator of the network 3) no, your security can have various levels of effectiveness, again depends a lot on the setup

Comment: This is just a personal network setup by a ISP that most people would use. Let's just agree that someone is purposefully doing something and gaining information about me somehow. This setup would be what you would find in most homes. Just basic internet setup

Comment: icic, for 2) I just wanted to know if there are equipment or apps that do what they claim to do, because if that's the case, whether legal or not, I'm just looking for possibility that someone couldn't care about that and purchase it anyways

Comment: Do you mean that it's a home network that was set up with a generic router provided by the ISP with the default setup? If yes, then I would guess that you are not an interesting enough target for someone to spend too much money and time on (on the other hand if you are such target, then you should consider your network completely compromised). In short I wouldn't worry too much about specialised equipment being used.

Comment: Let's just agree it's someone I know that is doing this, do those apps or equipment do what they claim they can do? i.e. just put in a number and you can hear their convos and record them

Comment: well, in theory you can spoof a mobile antenna, but if the target is just one person, it is better (and in some cases easier and safer) to compromise that person's phone. Anything is possible, including having someone mess up with your mind. If someone would actually go to such lengths in order to compromise your devices, then you need a security specialist. I don't think you can deal with this by following discussion board advices. However, you have to seriously consider the possibility that someone is just playing psychological games with you.